# Integrate Waze link/ any Application in Flex Mobile application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, hyperlink

how am i redirecting to app that in my mobile phone?
for example: Waze
and if its not installed to redirect to the market

i know how to do it in java:

```
try
 {
    String url = "waze://?q=Hawaii";
     Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( url ) );
    startActivity( intent );
 }
 catch ( ActivityNotFoundException ex  )
 {
   Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
 "market://details?id=com.waze" ) );
   startActivity(intent);
 }
```

how to do it in flex 4.6?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand.  Is this an Android or iOS specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no perfect way to do that.

As you need more universal solution, you can try an option to do this with native extensions, here is an example:
[Start Activity from Adobe AIR native extension for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959593/start-activity-from-adobe-air-native-extension-for-android)

However, you can try this:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891366
This is a discussion of how to pass intent URI to navigateToURL method.
It doesn't work for me - maybe I constructed invalid URI, or this feature was not included into release. 
However, you can open some standard apps like that with navitateToURL:

> In AIR, on mobile platforms, the sms: and tel: URI schemes are
>   supported. On Android, vipaccess:, connectpro:, and market: URI
>   schemes are supported. The URL syntax is subject to the platform
>   conventions. For example, on Android, the URI scheme must be lower
>   case. When you navigate to a URL using one of these schemes, the
>   runtime opens the URL in the default application for handling the
>   scheme. Thus, navigating to tel:+5555555555 opens the phone dialer
>   with the specified number already entered. A separate application or
>   utility, such as a phone dialer must be available to process the URL.
>
> The following code shows how you can invoke the VIP Access and Connect
>   Pro applications on Android:
>
> //Invoke the VIP Access Application. navigateToURL(new
>   URLRequest("vipaccess://com.verisign.mvip.main?action=securitycode"));
>   //Invoke the Connect Pro Application. navigateToURL(new
>   URLRequest("connectpro://"));

You can also try to use StageWebView class to manipulate standard browser which may support intent links in some way.